# MS Graph - appear to be getting authentication error after changing async/task and refactoring code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, async-await, microsoft-graph-api

This one has me stumped. I have some working code in an ASP.NET MVC controller where I needed to change the call tree to try and resolve a sync error (I think, I may undo it to test my theory).

Any way, the call tree before any changes was as follows, starting at the top:

```
public override async Task<ActionResult> Index()

    var tmp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("name").Value;
    GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = this.GetGraphServiceClient();
    var response = await GetGraphUser();
```

Then the method itself looks like this:

```
private async Task<UserModel> GetGraphUser()
{
    UserModel user = new UserModel();
    
    try
    {
        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = this.GetGraphServiceClient();
        //
        var myInfo = await graphServiceClient.Me
                               .Request()
                               .Select("onPremisesSamAccountName,displayName,userPrincipalName")
                               .GetAsync();
```

Now we've changed it to remove the async from the `Index` method, so this is what we have:

```
public override ActionResult Index()
{
    // ... stuff ...
    GetUserInfoFromMSGraphHC();
}
```

which calls this:

```
public bool GetUserInfoFromMSGraphHC()
{
    try
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var UserInfo = await GetGraphUserHC(PersonnelID);
            }
    }
    catch(...)
    {  }
}
```

And then:

```
public async Task<UserModel> GetGraphUserHC(string pid)
{
    try
    {
        UserModel gUser = new UserModel((ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("sAMAccountName").Value));

        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = this.GetGraphServiceClient();
           //
        var myInfo = await graphServiceClient.Me
           .Request()
           .Select("onPremisesSamAccountName,displayName,userPrincipalNames")
           .GetAsync();
```

In this second case, I get the following error on the line

```
myinfo = await graphServiceClient.Me
```

> General Exception Error calling MsGraph - Code: generalException
> Message: An error occurred sending the request.
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at Microsoft.Identity.Web.Hosts.OwinTokenAcquisitionHost.GetAuthenticatedUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user)
> at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.d__16.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.Identity.Web.DefaultAuthorizationHeaderProvider.d__2.MoveNext()

This seems to me it might be related to authentication in some way.  That logic is in the Startup and is identical so I've excluded it. The only other auth related part I could think of was the `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` stuff, which is why I added it to the new code in the last method so I could confirm it worked.